# Java: A variable as a link to class

Tags: java, game-engine

If you ever heard of Nethack, you are familiar with such gameplay feature as *polymorph*.

In a Java game I'm modding, mobs (hero, monsters) are stated as Java classes, which all extend the very base *Char.java* class. I'm trying to add a new field to this base class: a public *current_form* field, which is supposed to be a link to the class that represents your, or monsters' current form.

Base *Char.java* class would have *attack()*, *move()*, and some more methods which will trigger *current_form.attack()*, *current_form.move()* respectively, where current_form is replaced with classname.

So if I have the class Hero (extends Char):

```
Hero h = new Hero();
```

and I attack:

```
h.attack();
```

it will trigger a `do_attack()` method as my current form (read: from a class named as my current form), if my form is `Rat.class`, it will trigger `Rat.do_attack()` respectively.

How do you achieve this kind of a behaviour?

Comment: You have a variable that refers to an appropriate *instance* of the class representing the current form, not to the class.  You invoke methods on that instance normally.  There are opportunities here for a refactoring, but that would involve more and larger changes.

Answer (score 2):

It could be something along the lines of

```
public class Hero extends Char {
    Char polymorphedTo;

    public void attack() {
        if(polymorphedTo != null)
            polymorphedTo.attack();
        else
            normalAttackCode();
    }
}
```

This allows an easy way to redirect any suitable actions to the code for the form that you're polymorphed into.

Comment: How would you set polymorphedTo? Also it needs to be in Char class, not the hero, because every character (mobs too) can polymorph.

Comment: How do you generally set variables? This answer is intended to give you an idea how to do it. You can put it in `Char` or `Hero` or anywhere it fits best.

Comment: Do you set it like `Hero.class` or `Hero.this`? I do not need to create a new mob every time I polymorph though.

Comment: You could even set `polymorphedTo` to `this` when the character is in its natural form.  Then `attack()` could **unconditionally** perform `normalAttackCode()`.

Comment: @LexLaiden Yes, you create a new instance every time you polymorph, or keep a list of ready made instances as long as they don't keep state (health etc.). So `hero.polymorphInto(new Rat());` or `hero.polymorphInto(Rat.DEFAULT_INSTANCE);` (where `DEFAULT_INSTANCE` would contain a single constant instance of that particular class).

Comment: Setting polymorphedTo to Hero.this throws an error "dungeon.actors.hero.Hero" is not an enclosing class

Comment: @LexLaiden You can't get this to work with just guessing and randomly trying code. What I showed was a very broad example. My code assumed that you would do `hero.polymorphInto(new Rat());` (for example).